# How to make Sublime Text 3 to move the cursor to the next line after ctrl + / comment?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to comment out pieces of code with one-line comments without using the arrows, like I do in IDEA, but Sublime Text 3 stays on the same line after commenting. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a Macro for this that combines together the commands for toggling a line comment and then moving the cursor, and then rebinding the key to run the macro.

Such a macro would look something like the following. Here this is saved as `Packages\User\comment_line.sublime-macro`.

```json
[
    {
        "command": "toggle_comment",
        "args": {"block": false }
    },
    {
        "command": "move",
        "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true }
    }
]
```

With this in place, you can add a binding such as the following to your custom key bindings:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+/"],
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/comment_line.sublime-macro"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": "true", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

If you change the name of the macro when you save it, that needs to be reflected here.

This binding includes a context that makes it only apply when there is no selection, in which case this binding will be ignored and Sublime will use the default instead.

That can be removed if you wish. However, WebStorm (the only JetBrains tool I have handy at the moment) operates in this fashion, so presuming that IntelliJ does as well this more accurately mimics what happens there.

Additionally, if you're mapping a *different* key to the comment command, make sure the original line is **above** the new addition:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+q"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+q"],
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/comment_line.sublime-macro"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": "true", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but I have error "Unable to open res://Packages/comment_line.sublime-macro" when I press ctrl + /. It seems like no one else have had such a problem.

Comment: You're missing part of the path; it should be `"res://Packages/User/comment_line.sublime-macro"`. Double check that you copied everything correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There's a plugin called "Chain of Command" which can be found in here: https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand

Once you have it installed, you can simply add the following to your key bindings:

```
{
    "keys": ["super+forward_slash"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["toggle_comment", { "block": false }],
            ["move", { "by": "lines", "forward": true }]
        ]
    }
}
```